# How to work out how to resolve a performance issue using the threading tools in Mule?

Tags: performance, jvm, mule, performance-testing, anypoint-studio

I am using Anypoint Studio 6.1 and Mule 3.8.1 and have a workflow that is not performing as the thread monitoring looks like alot of the 250 max active threads are not being used even though the flow is being called by 250 concurrent users in an infinite loop from JMeter 3.1.

I have used tools like VisualVM and YourKit to investigate the problem and try to identify a solution.  It looks like the majority of threads are parked or waiting but I'm not sure how you go about finding the optimal performance solution from the thread dumps and the analysis tools?

**TEST XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
    xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:mongo="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo/current/mule-mongo.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd">
    <ee:object-store-caching-strategy name="Caching_Strategy" doc:name="Caching Strategy">
        <managed-store storeName="cacheManagedObjectStore" maxEntries="1000" entryTTL="846000" expirationInterval="846000"/>
    </ee:object-store-caching-strategy>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Config" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" basePath="/api" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration">
        <http:worker-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="250" maxThreadsIdle="2" threadTTL="10000" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT" threadWaitTimeout="10000" maxBufferSize="0"/>
    </http:listener-config>
    <flow name="testFlow" initialState="started">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Config" path="/perf-test" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-payload value="#['{&quot;EffectiveEndDateTime&quot; : null}']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <ee:cache cachingStrategy-ref="Caching_Strategy" doc:name="Cache">
            <mongo:find-documents config-ref="Mongo_DB__Configuration" collection="${test.collection}" doc:name="Mongo DB"/>
            <json:object-to-json-transformer encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
        </ee:cache>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

**MONITORING GRAPHS**
[image]

**GARBAGE COLLECTION**
[image]

**THREADs**
[image]

[image]

**THREAD DUMP SNAPSHOT (FULL LOG TOO BIG)**

```
2017-02-16 21:59:58
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.112-b15 mixed mode):

"[test-project].HTTP_Listener_Config.worker.147" #263 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000002636e800 nid=0x31a0 waiting on condition [0x000000003efce000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006da7ec940> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"[test-project].HTTP_Listener_Config.worker.91" #207 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000027dfc000 nid=0x1988 waiting on condition [0x000000003b7ce000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006da7ec940> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"RMI TCP Connection(3)-192.168.0.16" #200 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000027df9000 nid=0x4668 runnable [0x000000003afcd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
        - locked <0x00000006d885d660> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00000006d885e008> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"pool-1-thread-1" #153 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000027bb6000 nid=0x5524 waiting on condition [0x0000000035b2f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006da8578e8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"[test-project].HTTP_Listener_Config.worker.38" #152 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000027bb8000 nid=0x2988 waiting on condition [0x0000000035a2f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006da7ec940> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"cluster-ClusterId{value='58a620afa3cb7258cc6cd828', description='null'}-test-project-shard-00-02.mongodb.net:27017" #151 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000027bb9800 nid=0x33c0 waiting on condition [0x000000003495e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006daa03680> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForSignalOrTimeout(DefaultServerMonitor.java:238)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForNext(DefaultServerMonitor.java:219)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:168)
        - locked <0x00000006daa03650> (a com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"cluster-ClusterId{value='58a620afa3cb7258cc6cd828', description='null'}-test-project-shard-00-01.mongodb.net:27017" #150 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000027bbc800 nid=0x208c waiting on condition [0x000000003485f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006da856910> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForSignalOrTimeout(DefaultServerMonitor.java:238)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForNext(DefaultServerMonitor.java:219)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:168)
        - locked <0x00000006da8568e0> (a com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"[test-project].HTTP_Listener_Config.worker.37" #149 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000027bbb000 nid=0x3668 waiting on condition [0x000000003475f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006da7ec940> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"cluster-ClusterId{value='58a620afa3cb7258cc6cd828', description='null'}-test-project-shard-00-00.mongodb.net:27017" #148 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000027bbc000 nid=0x2844 waiting on condition [0x000000003465e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006daacb940> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForSignalOrTimeout(DefaultServerMonitor.java:238)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForNext(DefaultServerMonitor.java:219)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:168)
        - locked <0x00000006daacb910> (a com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"[test-project].HTTP_Listener_Config.worker.34" #145 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000027bb9000 nid=0x274 waiting on condition [0x000000003435f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006da7ec940> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"[test-project].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.02" #111 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001d6f3000 nid=0x24a8 waiting on condition [0x0000000030d8e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006da86d580> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"[test-project].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01" #110 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000261e7000 nid=0x4ee0 waiting on condition [0x0000000030c8e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006da86d580> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"DestroyJavaVM" #109 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000261e5800 nid=0x7330 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1" #108 prio=1 os_prio=-2 tid=0x00000000261e5000 nid=0x3d24 waiting on condition [0x000000003098f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006daacc138> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"[test-project].processing.time.monitor" #107 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000261e6800 nid=0x6268 in Object.wait() [0x000000002f6bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
        - locked <0x00000006d7a6bc10> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"[test-project].testFlow.stage1.01" #104 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000261dc800 nid=0x2fb4 in Object.wait() [0x000000002f3be000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at org.mule.util.queue.AbstractQueueStoreDelegate.poll(AbstractQueueStoreDelegate.java:81)
        - locked <0x00000006daa523b8> (a org.mule.util.queue.DefaultQueueStoreDelegate)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00000006da6616e8> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)


"Thread-8" #57 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000023cec800 nid=0x30c0 waiting on condition [0x000000002c4be000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006d9b219f8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"pool-7-thread-6" #56 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001eb5f800 nid=0x2914 waiting on condition [0x000000002bcbf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006d88e7270> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)

        Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"[test-project].http.listener.HttpIdleConnectionCloser.01" #50 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000241cd000 nid=0x2b50 in Object.wait() [0x000000002aa2f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.DelayedExecutor$DelayedRunnable.run(DelayedExecutor.java:172)
        - locked <0x00000006d8bdac18> (a java.lang.Object)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

        Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00000006d8bbf6c0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"[test-project].http.listener.worker(8)" #49 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000241d3800 nid=0xb34 waiting on condition [0x000000002a92f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006d8bcf9a8> (a java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"[test-project].http.listener.worker(7)" #48 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000241d3000 nid=0x67d4 waiting on condition [0x000000002a82e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006d8bcf9a8> (a java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"[test-project].http.listener(5) SelectorRunner" #41 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000241cf000 nid=0x4288 runnable [0x000000002a12e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.$$YJP$$poll0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(WindowsSelectorImpl.java)
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:296)
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:278)
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:159)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000006da0f16c0> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
        - locked <0x00000006da0f16d8> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000006d8a843c0> (a sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.select(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:115)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"[test-project].http.listener(4) SelectorRunner" #40 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001efaa000 nid=0x2bb0 runnable [0x000000002a02f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.$$YJP$$poll0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(WindowsSelectorImpl.java)
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:296)
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:278)
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:159)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000006d8bdac48> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
        - locked <0x00000006d8bdac60> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000006d8770f40> (a sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Log4j2-AsyncLoggerConfig-4" #36 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001daee000 nid=0x6afc waiting on condition [0x0000000026f1e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006d9a27c00> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00000006d6fa29f8> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"[test-project].Mule.01" #35 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001daec800 nid=0x114c waiting on condition [0x000000002544e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006d808bcc0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00000006d80a0ae8> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"Log4j2-AsyncLoggerConfig-3" #34 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001daeb800 nid=0x6274 runnable [0x0000000024b4e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
        - locked <0x00000006d697bce0> (a java.io.BufferedOutputStream)
        at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:480)
        - locked <0x00000006d68e2f20> (a java.io.PrintStream)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.CloseShieldOutputStream.write(CloseShieldOutputStream.java:50)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.write(OutputStreamManager.java:123)
        - locked <0x00000006d6c8f7f0> (a org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.write(OutputStreamManager.java:136)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00000006d80a0b18> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"Log4j2-AsyncLoggerConfig-2" #28 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001daef800 nid=0x6eec waiting on condition [0x000000002327f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006d7a78c00> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00000006d6e6d4a0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"agw-policy-watcher" #27 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001daf1000 nid=0x1870 waiting on condition [0x000000002317f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at org.apache.commons.io.monitor.FileAlterationMonitor.run(FileAlterationMonitor.java:188)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"MapDB writer #2" #24 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001daf0000 nid=0x6984 waiting on condition [0x000000002307f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:338)
        at org.mapdb.AsyncWriteEngine$WriterRunnable.run(AsyncWriteEngine.java:165)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"MapDB writer #1" #22 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001daee800 nid=0x6098 waiting on condition [0x0000000022f7f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:338)
        at org.mapdb.AsyncWriteEngine$WriterRunnable.run(AsyncWriteEngine.java:165)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"JMX server connection timeout 21" #21 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001e58f800 nid=0x3d50 in Object.wait() [0x0000000022e7f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ServerCommunicatorAdmin$Timeout.run(ServerCommunicatorAdmin.java:168)
        - locked <0x00000006d6e7e948> (a [I)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"RMI Scheduler(0)" #20 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001dba8800 nid=0x3590 waiting on condition [0x0000000022d7e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006d68e1878> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Log4j2-AsyncLoggerConfig-1" #19 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001d920000 nid=0x334 waiting on condition [0x0000000022c7f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006d68e99c0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00000006d68f47e0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"RMI TCP Connection(2)-192.168.0.16" #18 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001da4a000 nid=0x4eb8 runnable [0x0000000022b7d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        - locked <0x00000006daa99310> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00000006d68e9ba0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"RMI TCP Accept-0" #17 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001d793000 nid=0x273c runnable [0x000000002297e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
        - locked <0x00000006d68eded0> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Service Thread" #13 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001b40e800 nid=0x1478 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"C1 CompilerThread2" #12 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001bdcc800 nid=0x6d1c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"C2 CompilerThread1" #11 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001bdcb800 nid=0x1448 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"C2 CompilerThread0" #10 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001b40a000 nid=0x4144 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"VM JFR Buffer Thread" #9 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001b3fc000 nid=0x5e30 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"JFR request timer" #7 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000021824000 nid=0x135c in Object.wait() [0x000000002207e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000006d68e18c0> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
        - locked <0x00000006d68e18c0> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Attach Listener" #6 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001b2b6800 nid=0x1008 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Signal Dispatcher" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001b2b5000 nid=0x2da8 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001b2be000 nid=0xdd8 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x0000000021474800 nid=0x6fa0 in Object.wait() [0x0000000021c7f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
        - locked <0x00000006d68e18d8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:193)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000002144d800 nid=0x6b30 in Object.wait() [0x0000000021b7f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
        - locked <0x00000006d68e99f0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"VM Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000021441000 nid=0x5ad8 runnable 

"Gang worker#0 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000001875800 nid=0x401c runnable 

"Gang worker#1 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000001876000 nid=0x6060 runnable 

"Gang worker#2 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000001877800 nid=0x1fc runnable 

"Gang worker#3 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000001879000 nid=0x4a5c runnable 

"Concurrent Mark-Sweep GC Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x00000000018bd800 nid=0x17b8 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001be76800 nid=0x4dd0 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 17658
```

Comment: What does YourKit show you when looking at hot spots?

Answer (score 0):

The problem description doesn't seem to be correct. You mentioned "looks like alot of the 250 max active threads are not being used". Is that a problem? If the processing is efficient enough to answer all requests with less resource usage than the maximum allowed, then why would that be an issue? You'll need to clarify if you are seeing some actual problem related to that.

Thread dumps are mostly used to find thread locking issues, or threads delayed significantly in some task. For performance issues it would be better to use a profiler, like YourKit or the more limited one in VisualVM. Again, you need to define the problem more clearly to see what is the correct tool to use.